# Audit JPA entities eclipselink

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, audit

I need to audit updates, inserts and deletes, i'm using eclipselink as JPA provider. I need to store all modified data.

I tried to use @PrePersist for the merge but i don't know why, it is not called, and it's not possible to pass a object as my data before.

Other problem is that in update transactions i will need to store data as it was before and after the transaction to do a comparison, same in deleting, i need to store data that was deleted.

What is the best way to do this?

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners(FrotaListener.class)
@Table(name="frota" , schema="sap")
@NamedQuery(name="Frota.findAll", query="SELECT f FROM Frota f")
public class Frota implements Serializable {..}
```

```
public class FrotaListener {

@PrePersist
@PreUpdate
@PreRemove
private void beforeAnyOperation(Object object) { 
    System.out.println("teste"); 
    }
}
```

```
        try {
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.flush();
        em.merge(frota);
        em.flush();
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        sqlErrorParse(e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        em.close();
    }
```

and FrotaListener is never called